Azure user assigned managed Identity authentication fails
I have an app service in Azure, and I want to use it to send events to the Azure Event Hub.
I'm using a user-assigned managed identity that I connected to my app service.
I'm using:
new DefaultAzureCredential()

to authenticate, but Im getting this error:
ManagedIdentityCredential Authentication Failed

Service request failed.

Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Content:
{ "statusCode": 400, "message": "Unable to load the proper Managed Identity.", "correlationId": "183e1509-0635-4dc3-8463-d1891f7307c7" }
Headers:
Date: Sun, 14 Jul 2024 14:46:19 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-CORRELATION-ID: REDACTED
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

I can't really figure out what the issue is.
I tried restarting the web app, deleting the managed identity, and creating a new one, but the error persists.

Maybe some environment variables are missing?
See User Managed Identity unable to get tokens - Unable to load the proper Managed Identity,
Setup your environment for authentication and
Trying to Connect to Azure using Environment Credentials Not Working.

You need to specify the id for the user-assigned identity. Since you can add several of them, it needs to know which one you want to use. This does not apply to system-assigned identities.

Are you sure you really need a user-assigned managed identity in the first place? Can't you use a system managed identity instead? It makes live a little easier if you can and using new DefaultAzureCredential() will do the trick.


ManagedIdentityCredential Authentication Failed
Service request failed. Status: 400 (Bad Request) { "statusCode": 400, "message": "Unable to load the proper Managed Identity.", "correlationId": "183e1509-0635-4dc3-8463-d1891f7307c7" }

I agree with Juunas's comment, To authenticate with a user-managed identity, you need to specify the Client ID of your user-managed identity, and the system needs to know which one you want to use.
You can get the client id from your Azure portal.
Portal:

You can use client id like below in your code:
Code:
string userAssignedClientId = "<your managed identity client ID>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential( new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });

Full code to send an event the event hub with managed identity.
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer;
using System.Text;

int numOfEvents = 3;

string userAssignedClientId = "<your managed identity client ID>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential( new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });

EventHubProducerClient producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(
    "<EVENT_HUB_NAMESPACE>.servicebus.windows.net",
    "<HUB_NAME>",
    credential;

using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfEvents; i++)
{
    if (!eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Event {i}"))))
    {
        throw new Exception($"Event {i} is too large for the batch and cannot be sent.");
    }
}

try
{
    await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"A batch of {numOfEvents} events has been published.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
finally
{
    await producerClient.DisposeAsync();
}

Reference:
DefaultAzureCredential Class (Azure.Identity) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn
